# PySpark filter works only after caching

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a DF and its columns are '_id', 'time', 'message' -> loaded from MongoDB.

'message' is struct type and its value would look something like below

```
{data: { payload : { ChangeEventHeader : {changeType: 'AAA' }}}
```

when I try to execute below lines, it throws error filtering DF *message.data.payload.ChangeEventHeader.changeType does not exist*

```
df = df.withColumn('ctype', col('message.data.payload.ChangeEventHeader.changeType'))
df.show()
df.select(col('ctype')).show()
df.filter(col('ctype') == "AAA").show()
```

I don't understand the issue here. while it works for 'select', why not filter? anyone have faced it before? I've even tried to filter without creating 'ctype' column, still the same error.

The only workaround I found was caching df right before filter. Is it the right way to handle it?

Comment: was able to run this code without issue. I recommend not re-using and overwriting variable names like `df` in this scenario, as it can lead to confusion due to statefulness, especially in interactive/notebook environments.

Comment: @ZachKing exactly. It should work. I'm quite confused what I'm missing or messing up. So here is my evn - spark 3.2, databricks notebook, data read from MongoDB using spark mongo connector.

Comment: Also try to use `df.printSchema()` more, then you will see what the exact type of your column is.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you got this error because of the nested structure of the 'message' column in your DataFrame.

When you used `df.select(col('ctype')).show()`, it worked because you only selected the derived 'ctype' column, which doesn't require accessing the nested structure, but does not work when you run `df.filter(col('ctype') == "AAA").show()`

One suggestion to get this to work is to use the `getField()` function from pyspark.sql.functions to access the nested field directly.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, getField

df = df.withColumn('ctype', getField('message.data.payload.ChangeEventHeader.changeType'))
df.show()
df.filter(col('ctype') == "AAA").show()
```

as you mentioned, the other way it could work is caching:
caching the df will force Spark to flatten the message column, so that you can filter on it.

```
df.cache()
df.filter(col('ctype') == "AAA").show()
```

Comment: cannot import name 'getField' from 'pyspark.sql.functions'.  But getField is available on column. I tried  

n_df = df.withColumn('ctype', df.message.getField("data.payload.ChangeEventHeader.changeType"))  throws error "No such struct field data.payload.ChangeEventHeader.changeType in channel, data"

Comment: @JackJack maybe try caching your dataframe. It's not the most efficient, but might work. I updated my answer above with more details.

Comment: That I have already figured it out as a work around(see my question post). But not sure if that is the right way to resolve.